# RDP Windows 10 to Windows 2000 blurred graphics

Tags: windows-2000

I have problem with connection to remote machine by RDP in windows 10. Remote machine is windows 2010 and I'm using build in client: mstsc.exe

Graphics on desktop is blurred, like on screen. After logging some icons and text are also blurred.

[image]

When connecting to win2013 everything is ok.
On other machine with XP everything is ok too.

I tested many configuration of mstsc (compression etc.), but without success. Maybe someone helps ?

Comment: Did you try disabling `Persistent bitmap caching` under the Experience tab?

Comment: Yes, I tried. The same effect :(

Comment: I'm also getting this issue. Removing the persistent bitmap caching also didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!!

After extensive experimentation, a workaround was finally discovered for an incompatibility problem (scrambled text) between a Windows 10 64-bit Remote Desktop client and a Windows 2000 Advance Terminal Server with SP4.

The fix was to use the Windows 2012 R2 Remote Desktop client on the Windows 10 64-bit computer.

In order to use the W2K12 built-in RDP client on the Windows 10 64-bit computer, the three files below were copied from a Windows 2012 R2 Server to the Windows 10 64-bit computer after renaming the original files on the Windows 10 workstation.

However, before the three files could be renamed on the Windows 10 box, the ownership for each directory below was changed from the TrustedInstaller to an administrator account.

In addition, the W2K12 Server R2 Remote Desktop client running on the Windows 10 computer had to have its Experience Tab\Persistent bitmap caching setting disabled before the text would be displayed in a clear fashion.

C:\windows\system32
1. mstsc.exe
2. mstscax.dll

C:\windows\system32\en-US
3. mstsc.exe.mui

Good luck!

Tim Schnelbach

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and just found a solution.
I installed Terminal Services Client from the Disk1/Disk2 Client creation during installation of Windows 2000 Terminal service.
If you don't want to install, you can just simply copy Disk2 folder onto Windows 10 local drive, create a tile by right-click on the file mstsc.exe and select Pin to Start.
Click on the mstsc tile to run Terminal Service Client, enter Windows 2000 name and select resolution you like, hit Connect and enjoy!